# JQuery confirm/alert box not displaying properly

Tags: jquery

I am using one application when a user click on submit button he will get one alert/confirm  box. Now i am facing the problem is after 2-3 click the alert box is coming but the box is not stable it dissapear suddenly any help will be great and thank you in advance.

Here what am trying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="alert/js/alert.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alert/css/alert.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alert/themes/default/theme.css" type="text/css">-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<link href="alert/css/alert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="alert/themes/default/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="alert/js/alert.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.alert.open('confirm', 'Hello');

        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the alert.js script?

Comment: alert.js is the different style of box like alert box/confirm box.@Scimonster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default form submission when clicking on the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventdefault();
        $.alert.open('confirm', 'Hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: Any way i got the answer @Barmar the problem is in the form. if i am using form than it is not possible to stable the box but if not than it is stable. is there any way to display the box in side a form.i mean with a form submition?

Comment: If you disable the submission, I think it should be stable. You'll need to use AJAX to submit the form after getting the confirmation.